# Spring security not taking into account assigned roles to certain resources - Spring BOOT

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I'm working on Spring Boot Application that exposes a bundle of REST-APIS, was trying to apply a SecurityFilter, it wokred successfully but not entirely, i'm trying to consume those web services by roles and authorities, yet once logged in it doesn't care wether i have the access to that resource or not.

Spring Boot - Spring Security

Here is my Security code:

```
        @Configuration
        @EnableWebSecurity
        public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

            @Autowired
            private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
            @Autowired
            private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCyptPasswordEncoder;

            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCyptPasswordEncoder);
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                http.csrf().disable();
                http.formLogin();
                http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login/**", "/register/**").permitAll();
                http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/studentResource/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN");
                http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            }
        }


    @Service
    public class UserDetalsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

        @Autowired
        private UnivAccountService accountService;

        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            AppUser user = accountService.findByUsername(username);
            if (user == null)
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            user.getAuRoles().forEach(r -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(r.getRole())));
            return new User(user.getAuUsername(), user.getAuPassword(), authorities);
        }
    }
```

My REST-API

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/studentResource")
    public class UnivStudentApi {

        @Autowired
        private UnivStudentService studentService;

        @PostMapping(value = "/getStudentsBySearchCriteria")
        public <T> Pagination<UnivStudentDto> getStudentsBySearchCriteria(@RequestBody SearchRequest searchRequest,
                @RequestParam int page, @RequestParam int size) {
            return studentService.getStudentsBySearchCriteria(searchRequest, page, size);
        }

        @PostMapping(value = "/getStudentByIden/{stdIden}")
        public UnivStudentDto getStudent(String stdIden) {
            return studentService.getStudent(stdIden);
        }

        @PostMapping(value = "/addLaboratory")
        public UnivOperationResponse persistNewLaboratory(@RequestBody UnivLaboratoryDto univLab) {
            return studentService.persistNewLaboratory(univLab);
        }

        @PostMapping(value = "/add")
        public UnivOperationResponse persistStudent(@RequestBody UnivStudentDto student) {
            return studentService.persistStudent(student, student.getUstLab().getUlaIden());
        }

        @PostMapping(value = "/merge")
        public UnivOperationResponse mergeStudent(@RequestBody UnivStudentDto student) {
            return studentService.mergeStudent(student);
        }

        @PostMapping(value = "/delete")
        public UnivOperationResponse deleteStudent(@RequestBody Long studentIden) {
            return studentService.deleteStudent(studentIden);
        }

        @GetMapping(value = "/getStudents")
        public Pagination<UnivStudentDto> getStudents(@RequestParam int page, @RequestParam int size) {
            return studentService.getStudents(page, size);
        }

        @GetMapping(value = "/getStudentsByKW/{KW}")
        public <T> Pagination<UnivStudentDto> getStudentsByKeyWord(@PathVariable("KW") T t, @RequestParam int page,
                @RequestParam int size) {
            return studentService.getStudentsByKeyWord(t, page, size);
        }

        @PostMapping(value = "/findPhdDoc")
        public UnivStudentDto getStudent(@RequestBody Long studentIden) {
            return studentService.getStudent(studentIden.toString());
        }
    }
```

I have one User in my database : username : user, password user, ROLE : USER

For example if would want to access the following URL After a successful login:

> http://localhost:8080/studentResource/getStudents?page=0&size=3

I expect 403 **Forbidden** Response Code, but it doesn't stop me, it renders the results as if i'm allowed to consume that method.

Thanks in advance for any answers, solutions.

Comment: Why do you expect a 403 error? Your are logged in, therefore you can call the URL.

Comment: I am logged in as USER, this web service is restricted except those with ADMIN Role, got it ?

Comment: I’m getting the correct user with USER which is not supposed to be eligible for consuming that rest method

Comment: Can you try to add _role as postfix to your rolls in the database? E.g. admin_role

Comment: You mean update the column value from ADMIN to ADMIN_ROLE

Comment: @SoufianeRabii *I am logged in as USER, this web service is restricted except those with ADMIN Role* No, it isn't. You only restricted `POST` for that role but you make a `GET`.

Comment: How stupid i am, I think you’re right, I ll try it and tell you wether it worked or not

Comment: @dur worked, thank you so much